# Laravel Vapor .env file too large

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions, laravel-vapor, vapor-cli

I have .env file larger than 2000 characters. So I followed the Vapor Doc.

https://docs.vapor.build/projects/environments.html#encrypted-environment-files

I am deploying to environment canary. I have encrypted the .env.canary to .env.canary.encrypted and updated the env on vapor using vapor UI as:
`LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY=base64:4Tw6Mq+bu8Fq0XvaVRQjazEjkVbV63KAAyYUv7P7TE0=`

But after deployment when I run a command `php artisan tinker --execute="dump(getenv())"` from vapor UI, the content in the .env.canary.encrypted file do not reflect in the command output.

Here is my vapor.yml file:

```
id: 43299
name: example-project
separate-vendor: true
environments:
    canary:
        memory: 2048
        timeout: 30
        domain:
            - canary.example.com
        database: canary
        cli-memory: 1024
        runtime: docker
        build:
            - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader'
            - 'php artisan event:cache'
            - 'npm i && npm run build && rm -rf node_modules'
        deploy:
            - 'php artisan migrate --force'
```

.github/workflows/canary.yml

```
name: Canary Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: [ canary ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: 8.2
          tools: composer:v2
          coverage: none
      - name: Require Vapor CLI
        run: composer global require laravel/vapor-cli
      - name: Install Project Dependencies
        run: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
      - name: Deploy Environment
        run: vapor deploy canary
        env:
          VAPOR_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.VAPOR_API_TOKEN }}
```

Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong here? I have multiple environments, so am I missing any environment specific commands in yml file?

Comment: Do you have any errors on cli logs? If not try delete the key, redeloy just with new env and add the key then redeploy again. Also check with specific env as well php artisan tinker --execute="dump(env('YOUR_KRY')"